# Why isn't Modernizr loading in Drupal 7 info file?

Tags: drupal-7

> name = Lucas description = Drupal-thema gemaakt voor de kinderafdeling
>   AZ St-Lucas Gent. package = Core version = VERSION core = 7.x
>   stylesheets[all][] = style.css
>
> scripts[] = scripts/lib/modernizr.js
>
> settings[garland_width] = fluid
>
> ; Information added by drupal.org packaging script on 2013-02-20
>   version = "7.x" project = "drupal" datestamp = "1361393684"

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your JS file isn't at that location, meaning that Drupal will automatically avoid generating a 404 by omitting the call to the non-existent file.

You could also rely on the [Modernizr Drupal module](https://drupal.org/project/modernizr) and it takes care of placement for you. It can also keep Modernizr up to date more easily by supplying you with a drush command to refresh the file, along with a nice API that allows for custom builds to be generated more conveniently. Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

see the installation instructions to use modernizr http://drupal.org/project/modernizr